# Image Transforms and AWS

Tags: image-transforms, aws

I regularly use srcset to serve large images, such as heroes, and take advantage of Craft's image transform capabilities in the implementation, e.g. <img srcset="{{ image.getUrl('img500') }} 500w,...etc.

Curious to know if anyone has a clever solution for doing this when images are stored on AWS? I know I can still use transforms, but they will be saved on the webserver, not AWS. I could create subfolders in my AWS bucket and manually scale the images, but that is obviously not an ideal solution.

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you have AWS policy issue. Never seen the problem you've described [image]

Craft still will save images copy locally to improve speed. You can disable it using maxCachedCloudImageSize config and set it to 0.

Comment: thanks Dima - I did not realize that transformed images were stored on AWS. It does work for me.